# What is the difference between a Customer Gateway and Router

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

**Customer Gateway**

> A customer gateway is the anchor on your side of that connection. It
> can be a physical or software appliance.
>
> Customers can connect multiple customer gateways
> (CGW) to a single VPC virtual private gateway (VGW) or can connect a
> single router to multiple VPC VGWs.

Is there a difference between a router and customer gateway? From AWS faq section https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/#C9, it seems they are one and the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Customer Gateway is the generic name describing a device that can speak IPSec and terminate the tunnels.

It could be a router, it could be a Linux server, but perhaps the most commonly used device is a hardware firewall device from a vendor like Cisco, Juniper, Sonicwall, etc.

Some routers can serve the purpose, but many routers do not have the capability of performing all of the things a customer gateway needs to do.

The section called [Your Customer Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/NetworkAdminGuide/Introduction.html) is written from the perspective of explaining this device to a technical person responsible for implementing one.

> Your company has decided to use an optional Amazon VPC VPN connection that links your data center (or network) to your Amazon VPC virtual private cloud (VPC). A customer gateway is the anchor on your side of that connection. It can be a physical or software appliance.

It explains the necessary requirements in high-level, yet technical terms.